# Aquatic plants growing conditions

Tags: plant-recommendations, water

I am a beginner gardener. I wanted to know if aquatic plants can grow in a small (100 x 10 x 10 inch) outdoor water tank filled with clean tap water? Also, does the water have to be treated in any way?

Also, are there are any good books that you would suggest? And any particular water plants that would easily grow in London?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would take a step back. From your questions, it appears a good review would help you.

Aquatic plants, like any other type can grow well in any space they are given, with proper conditions. What is your goal with the 100x10x10? Are you growing for entertainment? Do you wish to engage in Aquaponics? If so, your yield might be limited.

Tap water, depending on where you are, can still contain salts, and if treated so, chlorine and iodine. Given all these factors, some treatment may be necessary.

You will probably get some London specific advise here, but you can add to it. For books, I suggest you visit libraries, local botanical gardens and book stores.

In addition, it always helps to find local resources. Speak to local master gardeners, gardening clubs etc. and if Aquaponics is your goal, speaking to store owners and employees will be very helpful. In most cases, they will want to make sure they sell you the appropriate equipment.

Since you are new, I would start small, even if you will set up the space right away, and expand with experience. If it is Aquaponics, your space is probably going to have limited yields. If you just want to grow plants for fun, this is plenty of space. I grew lotuses with my mom in India and here, I have grown fresh water plants very easily, in treated aquariums. I also have a couple growing right below the hose which leaks when on. This can be very fun!

Comment: I always have big pots without drainage...filled with water and lilies and fish.  Tap water also has fluorine besides the chlorine...iodine?  I used (gag) this water as well in the cities, because anything else is just too difficult to gather and transport!  All my fish and plants did very well however.  Created a sort of self perpetuating little ecosystem.  Changing the water was rare, but adding was constant.  One thing even if you don't have fish, that water will get to boiling temperatures if left in the sun without the shading by mature lilies.  Heartbreaking to find all your fish cooked.

Comment: My goal is to grow some pretty flowers or plants (maybe waterlilies?). Not really looking for it to be complicated or to do aquaponics. Really would like least amount of maintenance possible. Preferably no fish unless it is necessary to help the plants grow or keep the tank balanced. We don't get a lot of sun where the tank is placed.